# ArcGis layer query: Average annual precipitation for area in U.S

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, precipitation

I need to get average precipitation for certain land parcels. I've found several layers which could offer this information but queries do not return results or indicate error. Below is example of my request ( our application uses javascript api). I need result as number inches/yard or similar?

[Query: Average annual precipitation (inches/yr) (ID: 21)](https://geonet.esri.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fenviroatlas.epa.gov%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FNational%2FESN_CleanAir%2FMapServer%2F21%2Fquery%3Fwhere%3D%26text%3D%26objectIds%3D%26time%3D%26geometry%3D%257B%2522rings%2522%253A%255B%255B%255B-12451957.152355101%252C5442964.610850086%255D%252C%255B-12451383.874642963%252C5442888.173821801%255D%252C%255B-12451498.53018539%252C5441970.92948238%255D%252C%255B-12451995.370869244%252C5441970.92948238%255D%252C%255B-12451957.152355101%252C5442964.610850086%255D%255D%252C%255B%255B-12449855.13407726%252C5443041.047878372%255D%252C%255B-12448670.360138843%252C5442926.392335944%255D%252C%255B-12448632.1416247%252C5441779.836911668%255D%252C%255B-12449778.697048975%252C5441779.836911668%255D%252C%255B-12449855.13407726%252C5443041.047878372%255D%255D%255D%252C%2522spatialReference%2522%253A%257B%2522wkid%2522%253A102100%252C%2522latestWkid%2522%253A3857%257D%257D%26geometryType%3DesriGeometryPolygon%26inSR%3D102100%26spatialRel%3DesriSpatialRelIntersects%26relationParam%3D%26outFields%3D%26returnGeometry%3Dfalse%26maxAllowableOffset%3D%26geometryPrecision%3D%26outSR%3D102100%26returnIdsOnly%3Dfalse%26returnCountOnly%3Dfalse%26orderByFields%3D%26groupByFieldsForStatistics%3D%26outStatistics%3D%26returnZ%3Dfalse%26returnM%3Dfalse%26gdbVersion%3D%26returnDistinctValues%3Dfalse%26f%3Dhtml)

query that returns error
[Query: Annual Precipitation (ID: 0)](https://geonet.esri.com/external-link.jspa?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhydrology.esri.com%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FClimate%2FPrecip_Hillshade%2FMapServer%2F0%2Fquery%3Fwhere%3D%26text%3D%26objectIds%3D%26time%3D%26geometry%3D%257B%2522rings%2522%253A%255B%255B%255B-12451957.152355101%252C5442964.610850086%255D%252C%255B-12451383.874642963%252C5442888.173821801%255D%252C%255B-12451498.53018539%252C5441970.92948238%255D%252C%255B-12451995.370869244%252C5441970.92948238%255D%252C%255B-12451957.152355101%252C5442964.610850086%255D%255D%252C%255B%255B-12449855.13407726%252C5443041.047878372%255D%252C%255B-12448670.360138843%252C5442926.392335944%255D%252C%255B-12448632.1416247%252C5441779.836911668%255D%252C%255B-12449778.697048975%252C5441779.836911668%255D%252C%255B-12449855.13407726%252C5443041.047878372%255D%255D%255D%252C%2522spatialReference%2522%253A%257B%2522wkid%2522%253A102100%252C%2522latestWkid%2522%253A3857%257D%257D%26geometryType%3DesriGeometryPolygon%26inSR%3D102100%26spatialRel%3DesriSpatialRelIntersects%26relationParam%3D%26outFields%3D%26returnGeometry%3Dfalse%26maxAllowableOffset%3D%26geometryPrecision%3D%26outSR%3D102100%26returnIdsOnly%3Dfalse%26returnCountOnly%3Dfalse%26orderByFields%3D%26groupByFieldsForStatistics%3D%26outStatistics%3D%26returnZ%3Dfalse%26returnM%3Dfalse%26gdbVersion%3D%26returnDistinctValues%3Dfalse%26f%3Dhtml)

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.